# Time problems on my Synology NAS 1511 running Busybox linux

Tags: linux, time, time-synchronization, busybox

I'm running a MS windows, using Netbeans 7. I occasionally get a problem when I hit save, "This file was modified externally, are you sure you want to overwrite"

Further investigation has led me to believe that the problem is with the times being out of sync between the NAS and my computer. All the computers on our network sync their time with time.windows.com

Can anyone advise me on how to sync the linux box with time.windows.com, if this is possible?
Or can someone suggest an alternative method to syncing the time together?

I have 5 windows PCs and one mac. Netbeans is the only program that throws this error, I think because the way it is coded is to check the last time saved against the file's last modified date, which because the NAS is set to be 2 minutes behind the rest of the PCs it constantly gets confused.

The NAS is mounted through SAMBA if this makes any difference.

-------------------**Edits**------------------

```
BusyBox v1.16.1 (2011-04-08 10:13:58 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

blackbird> uname -a
Linux blackbird 2.6.32.12 #1613 SMP Fri Apr 8 10:10:14 CST 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_x86_1511+
blackbird>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility available on most if not all linux distribution called 'ntpdate'

More information can be found here, including some very nice installation documentation and examples.

http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/

Comment: Yeh, busy box doesn't have that. Any idea how I can install it? busy box doesn't have yum or apt-get either (although possibly because it's not redhat/debian based, I'm no expert here)

Comment: Busy Box is a window manager application which runs on top of X, which in turn runs on top of a linux or unix system.

Comment: can you open a terminal and provide the output from the command: uname -a ?

Comment: Oh! sorry for overstepping the mark there then. Okay here we go. See my question for the edit. Thanks! +1 for your effort

Comment: Thanks for the vote up, and were the instructions at the link I provided any help?